# Clickable image : How to cancel it

Tags: html

I have elements in list which i made clickable The problem is when i put image it would be clickable either the same as the last element in the list.
to be clear when i click on the image it opens the same link when i click on the last element in the list(Potatos)
How can i make the image Unclickable.

```html
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com" />Pizza</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.msn.com" />Tacos</li>
                <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" />Potatos</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Tacos.jpg" width=30% />
        </div>
```

Comment: you need to close your `a` tag mate that is why everything on your site is clickable.

Comment: but i read before that link tags is self closed, is that right ??!

Comment: It worked thank you mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right way to do them mate.

```html
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Pizza</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.msn.com">Tacos</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Potatos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Tacos.jpg" width=30% />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `<a href="http://www.google.com" />`, Anchor tag `<a>` is a container tag, which means it has an opening `<a>`and closing tag `</a>`. Declaring `<a />` means it's a non-container/self-containing tag, which is  wrong.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Pizza</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.msn.com">Tacos</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Potatos</a></li>
 </ul>
```